# GLIBC_2.18 not found but here in local-build

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, dynamic-linking

I am trying to use a library called *libai_driver_rhf.so* that I compiled with **local-build libraries** to use use it on a server without having to install required dependencies. But when I run the command `ldd libai_driver_rhf.so | grep "not found"`, I get this :

```
./libai_driver_rhf.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /home/k.masson/Documents/nuke/nuke_plugin_test/src/dependencies/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)
```

I had a much more not found errors before but I fixed them by downloading the correct libraries for my computer and putting them into a dependencies folder. I also had another higher *GLIBC* not found error before that I fixed by downloading and putting `libstdc++.so.6` into `dependencies/lib64`.

I also use a local-build compiler, *gcc 4.9.3* and *4.8.5* is installed on my machine.

I don't know if this has a link with the error, but here are the results of grep "GLIBC" when executing strings on my local lib and my machine lib.

For **dependencies/lib/libc.so.6**:

```
[k.masson@hauser24 src]$ strings dependencies/lib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.1
GLIBC_2.1.2
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBC_2.2.1
GLIBC_2.2.2
GLIBC_2.2.3
GLIBC_2.2.4
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.22
GLIBC_PRIVATE
__sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_4
__sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_3
__sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_1
__sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_0
__sys_errlist_GLIBC_2_4
__sys_errlist_GLIBC_2_1
__sys_errlist_GLIBC_2_3
__sys_errlist_GLIBC_2_0
___sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_3
___sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_4
___sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_0
___sys_nerr_GLIBC_2_1
.................................... much more
```

For **dependencies/lib64/libstdc++.so.6**:

```
[k.masson@hauser24 src]$ strings dependencies/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

For **/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6**:

```
[k.masson@hauser24 src]$ strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

And my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` looks like this :

```
[k.masson@hauser24 src]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/k.masson/gcc-4.9.3/lib:/home/k.masson/Documents/nuke/nuke_plugin_test/src/dependencies/lib64:/home/k.masson/Documents/nuke/nuke_plugin_test/src/dependencies/lib:/home/k.masson/Documents/nuke/nuke_plugin_test/src/dependencies/lib:
```

As I see, I don't know if it's really the case, **GLIBC_2.18** is not in **/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6**, does that mean that `ldd` is taking stdc into /usr/lib ? If this is the case, how can I change this ? Or this is not the case and I am wrong ? Which won't be surprising because I don't understand these linker issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded correct builds from [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net) and it works, it seems that the library I built my self were not correctly builded.

Comment: That's a good question, i don't really remember... I guess i just looked for the correct version (as suggested in the dependencies) built with the same GCC I was using

Comment: I open the [http://rpmfind.net/](http://rpmfind.net/) and search but the result is **Service Unavailable**, if you could remember it please update your answer. Thanks you

Comment: The site seems to be down. I can't do anything for you at this point.